# What's the deal with the WMD editor?

Tags: support, editor, open-source

In 2008 [Jeff announced](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/reverse-engineering-the-wmd-editor/) the plans for a wmd open source project, progress was made, then drobbins picked up for a few months and stuff seemed to progress for a while.

Since then there have been 6-7 forks, but it does appear this project has no leadership.

Does SO plan to contribute back to any of the wmd branches? (or is WMD special sauce?) [Which](http://wiki.github.com/tstone/jquery-markedit/) [one](http://wiki.github.com/derobins/wmd/) of [the branches](http://wiki.github.com/cky/wmd/) does SO sanction?

Comment: See also: [Where's the WMD editor open source project?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/71822/162705) and [Will the WMD repository ever be updated?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75677/162705)

Comment: I've flagged this as `Too localized` because it is specific to a certain point of time in the distant past when the `wmd-new` project existed. It no longer belongs on the site. Pagedown has replaced wmd-new, and Jeff and his minions now submit changes there.

Comment: Why is my answer deleted? Clearly this is no longer applicable.. and per the policies of MSO it should be closed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/ now host the completely refactored version of WMD; it's identical to the version running here except for a few Stack Exchange specific things (spoilers, syntax highlighting hints and so on).

Answer (score 6):

Honestly, I haven't had time to work on this at all, and Dana has been busy with other stuff.

Anyway, I asked Dana to make me an admin to the Google Code project and I checked in the latest GitHub derobins code into the repository:

http://code.google.com/p/wmd-new/source/browse/

There have been a few small SO changes I need to fold in, but they're relatively minor. I'll try to get to that sometime over the next few months.

Feel free to submit patches.

Comment: perhaps change the version control on google code to mercurial, it will make it much easier for people to submit patches.

Comment: @waffles I don't even have mercurial installed, so I think you should submit patches for now using the subversion patch facility -- just attach the .patch file to the issue page: http://code.google.com/p/wmd-new/issues/list

Answer (score 2):

Isn't [this](http://github.com/derobins/wmd) basically the equivalent of the markdownsharp code project, except under different ownership?

There's no tests for it though. Or wiki, but that's what you get from using github