# What HTML editor is used by Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, markdown, editor

The Stack Overflow HTML editor is the best I've seen. Is it available as a downloadable component?

Comment: +1 This is a good, development-related question and belongs here rather than on meta.

Comment: dupe http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25780/which-rich-text-editor-does-superuser-use http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36179/whats-the-deal-with-the-wmd-editor

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where's the WMD editor open source project?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71822/wheres-the-wmd-editor-open-source-project)

Answer (score 10):

Actually, it is a reverse-engineered, custom-updated version of WMD: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/wmd-editor-reverse-engineered/

Comment: Cool, thanks - and WMD is going MIT : http://code.google.com/p/wmd/

Answer (score 5):

[WMD](http://wmd-editor.com/)