# Updated Markdown Engine Redistribution?

Tags: discussion, markdown, technology, downloads

My understanding of SO's text formatting engine is that it is a modified version of Markdown.

- Is there a diff somewhere between the [official distribution](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) and SO's?
- Is the SO version of Markdown publicly available for download/building?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36179/whats-the-deal-with-the-wmd-editor http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25780/which-rich-text-editor-does-superuser-use http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43024/what-html-editor-is-used-by-stack-overflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the SO version of Markdown is written in C# and is available from [here](http://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/)