# Question is a duplicate of a deleted question

Tags: discussion, bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Duplicate of…[deleted post]”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43724/duplicate-of-deleted-post)

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533586/what-wysiwyg-editor-does-stackoverflow-use) (the links is now for 10k users) has been closed as duplicate, but I think the link to the duplicate question is not working.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Is it bad that, when I saw "[duplicate]" on the end of this questions title, I was sorta hoping that one of *its* dupes was deleted, too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The duplicated post was deleted for being off-topic, about a year after that question was closed.

Here on meta there's a [non-closed thread about the text editor that Stack Overflow uses](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43024/what-html-editor-is-used-by-stack-overflow).

Comment: Then why its duplicate still exists ?? On deleting a off-topic question its duplicate should also be deleted. Anyway any alternative of this question. I want to know about text editor used in stackoveflow. Thanks

Comment: @NAVEED: I've added a link to my post to a not-closed question about the text editor.