# Will the WMD repository ever be updated?

Tags: support, markdown, editor

If you check out the [github repository](https://github.com/derobins/wmd), the last update was March 2009. Version 3, I guess.

The team has added a lot of changes and fixes over the last two years. Is that the last open source revision? Is there some secret repository that I don't know about?

If github has been abandoned, could there be some indication of this? Either a link on the github page linking to Google Code, or removing the links from the Google Code page?

Comment: +1 for pointing out that it even exists :)

Comment: yeah, you're looking in the wrong place.

Comment: I see that now, @Jeff, the descriptions on both pages are really misleading and searching for the wmd repository led to links to github (more specifically, it led to blog.stackoverflow posts about the project), so there should really be a notice somewhere about that

Comment: See also: [What's the deal with the WMD editor?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/36179/162705) and [Where's the WMD editor open source project?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/71822/162705)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll want to check out [this Google Code project](http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/), where updates to WMD made by SO are pushed. [balpha](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/115866/balpha) actually just [made some changes](http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/source/list) like five minutes ago, so you should find that it's up to date.

Comment: Oh, I see. I've seen the Google Code page, but didn't know it hosted source code because of the comment on the start page: " *Actual development takes place on github (see links).* "

Comment: @Corey Oh, you're right...I hadn't noticed that before. It does seem a bit misleading, hmm.

Comment: Looking at that list, I should proof-read my commit messages more often :)

Comment: @balpha Heheh, I wouldn't have even noticed had you not brought it up. As far as the blurb on the front page goes, is it possible for someone to remove the part about development being on Github, under the assumption that it will no longer be?

Comment: @balpha how closely does the Google Code version match the version used on SO? For example I've noticed that markup like `<span style="color:red">test</span>` colours the text red on the GC version, but not on SO. Are there changes yet to be folded into GC?

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat: They'll never be identical; we have quite a few SO-specific additions (think spoiler, `[tag:something]`, [question link processing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80543/can-we-improve-the-automatic-titling-of-links-to-internal-urls) etc.) What you're referring to is the HTML sanitizer (which disallows `style=`), but we don't really consider it part of Markdown. [Here's the C# version](http://refactormycode.com/codes/333-sanitize-html); it's just a couple of regex replacements.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat: Here's the JavaScript version: http://pastebin.com/2jP4E8b5

Comment: @balpha: just to add, there is still a lot of non-specific functionality on SO that is not in wmd-new, including several bugs that were fixed a long time ago on SO :)

Comment: @balpha, where can I get help on using the editor? I have it installed, but it converts markdown to HTML client side... so if there's a form validation error, the form is displayed with all the HTML and no markdown... any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat: [the newly refactored version](http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/) includes the sanitizer now.