# Preview of automatic titles for raw links is limited to 30 URLs

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, hyperlinks, markdown-preview

While editing the [long FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites), I noticed that many [automatic titles of raw links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49433/replace-trilogy-raw-links-with-the-current-question-title) are [not shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMude.png) in the preview.

On page load I see a single XHR that, for example, includes question id 11740. But 11740 is not in the results, unless I replay that request and limit the number of ids. It seems the results are paginated, but no additional Ajax calls are made to get the 2nd and 3rd set:

```json
apiCallbacks["meta.stackoverflow.com"]({
  "total": 63,
  "page": 1,
  "pagesize": 30,
  "questions":
     [...]
```

(After page load, when chancing the troublesome URLs, I'm not seeing new Ajax calls for the troublesome URLs — but I guess that's just caused by some caching you're doing? Nice! Same results in Safari, Firefox and Chrome on a Mac.)

Comment: Yep, I didn't take pagination into consideration. The FAQ is probably the only post where that matters :)

Comment: @balpha, I actually posted here (rather than commented on [Can we improve the automatic titling of links to internal URLs?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80543/can-we-improve-the-automatic-titling-of-links-to-internal-urls/80546#80546)) so you can easily tag `status-bydesign`!

Comment: @Arjan: It's a trivial fix; might as well make it status-completed

Comment: You're not just increasing the page size, @balpha? ;-)

Comment: @Arjan: I know you'd just create a post that surpasses that page size :) No, the implementation for this is a queue anyway, so making sure this queue only handles 30 questions at once was all that's necessary

Comment: I sure would have! So now I'll have to make a post with 29 or 31 links, to validate, @balpha ;-) (Actually, one wouldn't even have to *save* such post: I like the way the Ajax calls are combined into one call, even when just pasting the Markdown of the FAQ into a new unsaved, post. Nice, very nice!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really a pathology (the FAQ is probably the only page where this even matters), but the fix was easy enough, so this will work after the next build.