# Progress of new WMD editor?

Tags: discussion, editor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Will the WMD repository ever be updated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75677/will-the-wmd-repository-ever-be-updated)

What's the latest on the progress with the wmd-new editor that the StackOverflow guys were doing?

As far as I can tell, there are 2 places to get the source to it; Github:
https://github.com/derobins/wmd

... and Google Code (with Mercurial; what was wrong with SVN?):
http://code.google.com/p/wmd-new/source/checkout

It looks like the Github one is out-of-date and so presumably deprecated, although I've never seen it deprecated publicly.

So I grabbed the version from Google Code, and it seems to work OK.  What's the deal, though?  Is it the same as the one being used on StackOverflow.com?  Could Jeff Atwood or someone make a blog post on this, as the last one he made on it was back in [Jan 2009](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/updated-wmd-editor/).

Oh, and I forgot to add... has the JQuery-ized version of WMD, which was mentioned in that post, now been done?  Presumably you meant implementing it as a jQuery plugin?  Just realized that the way the current WMD editor works (non-jQuery), you can only have 1 per page as it relies on hardcoded DIV IDs.  This is unfortunate... as a jQuery plugin, it would work really nicely and you could turn multiple DIVs into editors on one page.

Answer (score 3):

balpha is keeping the one in google up to date, see: http://code.google.com/p/wmd-new/source/list

The one in github is defunct.

We try to update it as we go, but do not guarantee an up to the second version with every change we have.

Comment: So is there still a plan to do a jQueryized version?  And are you working towards the 'WMD 3' which is mentioned in the comments in the repo's readme.txt?

Comment: @Jez, possibly ... we much prefer jquery, code is more concise.

Comment: Being able to remove certain buttons would be nice, too.  I read the readme.txt and it talks about how to install things client-side, but isn't that due for an update to add something about how one then configures things to submit the generated code to the server?  Also something is gonna be needed on the server to check the submission as one can't trust the client.

Comment: Where should we go for feature requests? Create a new issue in the google code repository?