# Where can I get the Stack Overflow post editor?

Tags: support, editor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the deal with the WMD editor?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36179/whats-the-deal-with-the-wmd-editor)
>   [Where's the WMD editor open source project?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71822/wheres-the-wmd-editor-open-source-project)

I'm looking to find the editor used on Stack Overflow and other Stack Exchange sites. Is it available somewhere?