# Offline markdown editor for draft answers

Tags: discussion, markdown, editor

I'm wondering if anybody else has the requirement of having an (offline) editor when posting long questions and answers and would prefer to create the text in a separate (offline) editor to reduce the risk of browser crashes and lost data?

I have found an online/offline editor that uses Markdown language, but is [StackEdit.io](https://stackedit.io/) 100% compatible with the Markdown used on Stack Exchange? Probably not.

I read that the markdown language used on Stack Exchange is based partly on Google's interpretation/definition of Markdown language. However I'm not sure if this is just for the script language part. [Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184108/202162) and [Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/202162).

I [searched around a bit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=WMD) and found out that at one point the project WMD was the base for the Markdown used on Stack Exchange, but has now been replaced with [Pagedown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/100779/202162).

Which leads me to my second question: What is the base for Markdown/Pagedown currently used on Stack Exchange?

Comment: The answer at [Where's the WMD editor open source project?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71822/wheres-the-wmd-editor-open-source-project/71825#71825) was updated in Dec 2015 so I assume that is still correct.

Comment: I tested `StackEdit.io` against the native Stack Exchange editor and there **are some inconsistencies** in how the markdown is formatted.

Comment: @RobertCartaino so what alternatives do I have? Do I have any? Or do I have to stick with the native stack exchange editor window? Has anybody ported the pagedown source to some other editor?

Comment: @hot2use I stopped testing `StackEdit.io` when it formatted single  <CARRIAGE RETURN>s literally (Stack would combine them into one line). I don't use offline editors, but StackEdit.io seems like a pretty solid implementation. Personally, I would use that unless someone suggests something better... and just proofread your posts prior to submission to make sure it appears as you intended.